# dot asterisk operator in c++

Tags: c++

is there, and if, what it does?

```
.*
```

Comment: Could you paste the code where you see this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's the pointer-to-member operator for use with pointer-to-member types.

E.g.

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    A obj;
    int A::* ptr_to_memb = &A::b;

    obj.*ptr_to_memb = 5;

    ptr_to_memb = &A::a;

    obj.*ptr_to_memb = 7;

    // Both members of obj are now assigned
}
```

Here, `A` is a struct and `ptr_to_memb` is a pointer to `int` member of `A`. The `.*` combines an `A` instance with a pointer to member to form an lvalue expression referring to the appropriate member of the given `A` instance `obj`.

Pointer to members can be pointers to data members or to function members and will even 'do the right thing' for virtual function members.

E.g. this program output `f(d) = 1`

```
struct Base
{
    virtual int DoSomething()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

int f(Base& b)
{
    int (Base::*f)() = &Base::DoSomething;
    return (b.*f)();
}

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual int DoSomething()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    std::cout << "f(d) = " << f(d) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You may come across that operator when using member pointers:

```
struct foo
{
    void bar(void);
};

typedef void (foo::*func_ptr)(void);

func_ptr fptr = &foo::bar;
foo f;

(f.*fptr)(); // call
```

Also related is the `->*` operator:

```
func_ptr fptr = &foo::bar;
foo f;
foo* fp = &f;

(fp->*fptr)(); // call
```

Comment: It's not a combination -- it really is a single operator (per §§ 2.12, 5.5 of the standard). FWIW, `->*` is also a single operator (same references).

Comment: @sbi: What are you talking about...? :) @Jerry: I meant combination of actual symbols, not combination of operators. I suppose it is confusing.

Comment: @GMan -- yup. I have to admit I was a bit surprised at the idea you wouldn't have known it was a single operator...

Comment: @GMan: Um, I thought, for moment, you had written "member _function_ pointer" there. Sorry. `<shrug>`

Comment: @sbi: I actually had, I edited it out shortly after posting. :) You caught me.